# Google Chrome 20 fails to start in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-12.04

Several days ago Google Chrome stoped working after an update.

If I start it in the terminal I can see the following output:

```
[6:6:4528137750:FATAL:sandbox_init_linux.cc(378)] prctl(PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS) failed: Invalid argument
```

Any idea how to solve this?

**Chrome version:** 20.0.1132.47
**Ubuntu:** 12.04 x64
**Kernel:** 3.2.0-21-generic #34-Ubuntu

**EDIT**:
It is possible to start chrome with `--no-sandbox` switch.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing chrome? You can get the .deb from https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/?hl=en& and retry.

Comment: @hnns: Yes. I've reinstalled it but no luck.

Comment: I have been looking in the source code of chromium and in the source code of linux kernel and I think there are an incompatibility. The value of `PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS` changed in kernel and altough it also changed in Chromium I think that in my system either Chrome or Kernel are still using the old value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After been looking for both Chromium and Linux Kernel sources, I found an incompatibility between the versions stated above in the question.

In the newest versions of the Linux Kernel, the values of `PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS` and `PR_GET_NO_NEW_PRIVS`, defined in `<linux/prctl.h>`, has changed.

The version `20.0.1132.47` of Google Chrome has accomodate that changes but the version `3.2.0-21-generic #34-Ubuntu` of the Kernel has not.

So basically the solution is one of the following:

- Update the kernel to a newer version (version `3.2.0-22.35` and newer solves the problem)
- Downgrade Google Chrome to a version prior than `20.0.1132.47`